# meteor : comparing in template #if parties.owner == currentUserId?

Tags: templates, meteor

I very new to meteor 
I'm adding the update feature to the parties demo 
I now would like to only show the "Modify" button to the party's owner 
I tried

```
{{# with party}}
{{#if owner currentUser }}
    <br/><input type="button" value="Modifier" class="btn btn-small edit">
    {{/if}
```

but offcourse this is not the right way to do it 
I can't find how to access the user object in the template to compare it

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always have access to the Template object instance with `this` (a `party` instance in this example) inside the helper methods:

```
Template.details.isOwner = function() {
    return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
};

{{#if isOwner}}
    <br/><input type="button" value="Modifier" class="btn btn-small edit">
{{/if}}
```

(It's very similar to the `canRemove` helper that's already in the `Parties` example.)